# Git replace 2 versions same aplication (folder to repo)

Tags: windows, git, gitkraken

I use windows, Git and GitKraken as Git Client

I have 2 versions of same application: v1 and v2 (updated version of v1)

I have a git repository for v1 located in c:/app1/

The v2 is located in c:/app2 but without repository or anything, is simply a folder than contains an updated version of v1, some same files but new files too.

So, I need to replace/overwrite the app1 files, located in its repository with the same files located in the app2 folder and erase the old files in app1 that are no longer in app2

What is the safest way to do it? Can I erase app1 files and copy/paste?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a couple of things things.
You can create a new repo for AppV2.(very clean an not a lot of work)

or you can replace all files in the app1 folder except for the .git folder and de .gitignore file.

The last option is empty the app1 repo and point it to the app2 folder.